# Mysql mapping table FK constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm experiencing some difficulties with foreign key constraints. I have three tables:

```
Features
    ID PK AUTO_INC
    Title VARCHAR
Subscriptions
    ID PK AUTO_INC
    Title VARCHAR
Subscriptionfeatures
    ID PK AUTO_INC
    feature_id INT (index)
    subscription_id INT (index)
```

When I have the following records

```
Features
    1    Testfeature
Subscriptions
    1    Testsubscription
```

I can insert the following record in Subscriptionfeatures when defining a FK constraint as follows

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptionfeatures ADD CONSTRAINT FK_feature FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id);
Subscriptionfeatures
    x    1    1 => ok
```

But I can not insert the identical record when adding an ON DELETE CASCADE clause to the FK constraint, but i must admint i do not understand its reason for denial!

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptionfeatures ADD CONSTRAINT FK_feature FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
Subscriptionfeatures
    x    1    1 => fails
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you look into my query you will see that I first added the values and then created the constraint. That means that the data did exists. Could you please post the whole command sequence that fails and the exact error description?

Comment: I overlooked that. I did some further testing. Eventually it seems it's my own stupid mistake! I was testing using Emma to insert the records and did not press enter after inserting the last id in a new row, so when submitting the value was not set in the sql query.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE Features (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Title VARCHAR(100)
        ) Engine=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE Subsriptions (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        Title VARCHAR(100)
        ) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Subscriptionfeatures (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        feature_id INT NOT NULL,
        subscription_id INT NOT NULL,
        KEY ix_subscriptionfeatures_feature (feature_id),
        KEY ix_subscriptionfeatures_subscription (subscription_id)
        )  Engine=InnoDB;
INSERT
INTO    Features
VALUES  (1, 'Testfeature');
INSERT
INTO    Subsriptions
VALUES  (1, 'Testsubscription');

ALTER TABLE subscriptionfeatures ADD CONSTRAINT FK_feature FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES features(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT
INTO    Subscriptionfeatures (feature_id, subscription_id)
VALUES  (1, 1);
```

What is the error the `MySQL` gives?